# Change position of panel in stimul report

Tags: asp.net, runtime, controls, report, stimulsoft

I have an stimul report in asp.net and I need to change position of a panel dynamically in run time.
My question is how can I access the panel object in my code?
I need to change the top property of this control

Comment: What panel do you want to move?

Comment: I want to change stiPanel top property, but it doesn't effect in the report

Comment: When do you want to change it?

Comment: When a button is pressed, for example. I want to add it's top property step by step until right position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the Top property of the Panel with next code:

```
(report.GetComponentByName("Panel1") as StiPanel).Top = 15;
```

Comment: It works but for the first time the page loads, I want the user to define it's right place

Comment: If you want to do so in the Viewer you should use the same code and will need to render report again.

Comment: I don't know why but any component I did search returned null !

Comment: Did you load any report template? What do you get from report.GetComponents().Count?

Answer (score 0):

You should load report first, then direct cast object, then compile report before calling show()

```
  report.Load(Application.StartupPath & "report.mrt")  
  DirectCast(report.GetComponentByName("Image1"), StiImage).Stretch = False
  report.Compile()
  report.RegData(MyDataSet)
  report.Show()
```